# Selecting Variable Length Strings Among Multiple Strings in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I need a function or more likely a regex script that will allow me to pick out text strings based on a condition.

Example:

```
Input <- c("Red1 Orange", "Yellow Green2", "Blue3 Violet")
```

Leads to: "Red1", "Green2", "Blue3"

I have tried variety of options including:

```
str_extract(NamesCor, "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9]|
            [a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9]|
            [a-z][a-z][0-9]")
```

Which returns reen2, blue3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
stringr::str_extract(Input, "\\b[A-Za-z]+\\d+\\b")
stringr::str_extract(Input, "\\b\\p{L}+\\d+\\b")   # A Unicode aware version
```

See [R demo](https://rextester.com/IVDJT92071):

```
Input <- c("Red1 Orange", "Yellow Green2", "Blue3 Violet")
library(stringr)
str_extract(Input, "\\b[A-Za-z]+\\d+\\b")
## [1] "Red1"   "Green2" "Blue3"
```

See also the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BFW8CL/1). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters (`\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

Answer (score 3):

in `Base R`.

```
 gsub(".*?([0-9]\\w+|\\w+[0-9]).*","\\1",Input)
   [1] "Red1"   "Green2" "Blue3"
```

or

```
gsub(".*?(\\d\\w+|\\w+\\d).*","\\1",Input)
   [1] "Red1"   "Green2" "Blue3"
```

I like to use this [cheat sheet for regular expressions in R](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub` in base R :

```
sub('.*?([A-Za-z]+\\d+).*', '\\1', Input)
#[1] "Red1"   "Green2" "Blue3"
```

This captures characters followed by numbers.